# How can I get a list of text from an xml document using c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document which is as follows

```
<meta>
<field type="xs-string" name="Category">جداول</field>
<field type="struct" name="Images">
    <field type="xs-string" name="FileName">A00000002.png</field>
    <field type="xs-string" name="FileName">B00000002.png</field>
    <field type="xs-string" name="FileName">C00000002.png</field>
</field>
</meta>
```

I want to extract A00000002.png B00000002.png C00000002.png as a list using XDocument. My code at the minute is:

```
var images = (from title in doc.Root.Elements("field").Where(node => node.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Images")) select (string)title.Value);
```

But it only returns a string with all the image names beside each other ... Anyone know how I can get the list of image names, without hacking the string apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below menioned code

```
 var node = doc.Descendants("field").Elements("field").Select(p=>p.Value);
```

so you will get the List of Images Name.

O/P

[image]

you can use it like

```
 foreach (var item in node)
        {
            string value = item.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: yes, this now contains the list of strings in 'results view'... Any idea how I can access them?

Comment: I have modified my ans

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split()` function to get an array of string and convert it to List if necessary: pertinent to your case,

```
string[] _arrImages = ((string)images).Split([separator])
```

where separator is a proper delimiter char, e.g. (' ').
String array _`arrImages` can be converted to `List<string>` by applying `_arrImages.ToList()` function if necessary. Rgds,

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the fact that you don't enumerate the `Images`, but instead return the contents of it, which is the string you have shown.

Try this one:

```
var images = from title in doc.Root.Elements("field").Where(node => node.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Images")).Descendants().Where( node => node.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("FileName")) select (string)title.Value;
```

It walks the sub elements in a second `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Regex.Split` to your query result :

```
    XElement rootElement = XDocument.Load(@"YourPath").Root;

    var images = (from title in rootElement.Elements()
                .Where(node => node.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Images"))select (string)title.Value);

    string[] GroupsItems = Regex.Split((string)images, "png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
var mynode = doc.Descendants("field").Elements("field").Select(f=>f.Value);
```